# Lightning Lag- Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have several objects that "fall" from the top of the screen and when they are tapped lightning strikes them. My problem is, when one of the objects are tapped and lightning strikes my FPS goes down and the game lags.

Can someone please help me reduce this lag or lead me in the right direction? I have no clue on how to fix it. My game is finished and this is the only thing holding me back...

Here is the lightning code.

Lightning.h

```
//
//  Lightning.h
//  Trundle
//
//  Created by Robert Blackwood on 12/1/09.
//  Copyright 2009 Mobile Bros. All rights reserved.
//

#import "cocos2d.h"

/*! This will draw lighting and return the midpoint */
CGPoint drawLightning(CGPoint pt1, CGPoint pt2, int displace, int minDisplace, unsigned long randSeed, float width);
void drawSmoothLine(CGPoint *pos1, CGPoint *pos2, float width);
void drawSmoothPointAt(CGPoint *pos, float width);
void fillSmoothRectangle(CGRect *r, float width);

@interface Lightning : CCNode <CCRGBAProtocol>
{
    CGPoint _strikePoint;
    CGPoint _strikePoint2;
    CGPoint _strikePoint3;

    ccColor3B   _color;
    GLubyte     _opacity;
    BOOL        _split;
    BOOL        _glow;

    int _displacement;
    int _minDisplacement;
    float _lighteningWidth;

    unsigned long _seed;
}

@property (readwrite, assign) CGPoint strikePoint;
@property (readwrite, assign) CGPoint strikePoint2;
@property (readwrite, assign) CGPoint strikePoint3;
@property (readwrite, assign) ccColor3B color;
@property (readwrite, assign) GLubyte opacity;
@property (readwrite, assign) BOOL split;
@property (readwrite, assign) BOOL glow;
@property (readwrite, assign) int displacement;
@property (readwrite, assign) int minDisplacement;
@property (readwrite, assign) float lighteningWidth;
@property (readwrite, assign) unsigned long seed;

+(id) lightningWithStrikePoint:(CGPoint)strikePoint strikePoint2:(CGPoint)strikePoint2;

-(id) initWithStrikePoint:(CGPoint)strikePoint strikePoint2:(CGPoint)strikePoint2;

-(void) strikeRandom;
-(void) fade;

@end
```

Lightning.m

```
//
//  Lightning.m
//  Trundle
//
//  Created by Robert Blackwood on 12/1/09.
//  Copyright 2009 Mobile Bros. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Lightning.h"

@implementation Lightning

@synthesize strikePoint = _strikePoint;
@synthesize strikePoint2 = _strikePoint2;
@synthesize strikePoint3 = _strikePoint3;
@synthesize color = _color;
@synthesize opacity = _opacity;
@synthesize displacement = _displacement;
@synthesize minDisplacement = _minDisplacement;
@synthesize lighteningWidth = _lighteningWidth;
@synthesize seed = _seed;
@synthesize split = _split;
@synthesize glow = _glow;

+(id) lightningWithStrikePoint:(CGPoint)strikePoint strikePoint2:(CGPoint)strikePoint2
{
    return [[[self alloc] initWithStrikePoint:strikePoint strikePoint2:strikePoint2] autorelease];
}

-(id) initWithStrikePoint:(CGPoint)strikePoint strikePoint2:(CGPoint)strikePoint2
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        _strikePoint = strikePoint;
        _strikePoint2 = ccp(0, 0);
        _strikePoint3 = strikePoint2;

        _color = ccc3(255, 190, 255);

        //random style
        _displacement = 100 + CCRANDOM_0_1() * 200;
        _minDisplacement = 4 + CCRANDOM_0_1() * 10;
        _lighteningWidth = 2.0f;
        _split = YES;
        _glow = YES;

        [self strikeRandom];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void) draw
{
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glColor4ub(_color.r, _color.g, _color.b, _opacity);

    drawLightning(_strikePoint3, _strikePoint, _displacement, _minDisplacement, _seed, _lighteningWidth);

    if (_glow)
    {
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);
        glColor4ub(50, 0, 255, _opacity);
        drawLightning(_strikePoint3, _strikePoint, _displacement, _minDisplacement, _seed, 7);
    }

    if (_opacity != 255)
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    if (_opacity != 255)
        glBlendFunc(CC_BLEND_SRC, CC_BLEND_DST);

    glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

-(void) strikeRandom
{
    _glow = YES;
    _seed = rand();
    [self fade];
}

- (void) removeLightning {
    self.visible = NO;
}

- (void) fade
{
    self.visible = YES;
    self.opacity = 255;

    [self runAction:[CCSequence actions: 
                    // [DelayTime actionWithDuration:1.0],
                     [CCShow action],
                     [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:0.5],
                     [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(removeLightning)],
                     nil]];
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end

int getNextRandom(unsigned long *seed)
{
    //taken off a linux site (linux.die.net)
    (*seed) = (*seed) * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return ((unsigned)((*seed)/65536)%32768);
}

CGPoint drawLightning(CGPoint pt1, CGPoint pt2, int displace, int minDisplace, unsigned long randSeed, float width)
{   
    CGPoint mid = ccpMult(ccpAdd(pt1,pt2), 0.5f);

    if (displace < minDisplace)
    {
        //ccDrawLine(pt1, pt2);
        drawSmoothLine(&pt1, &pt2, width);
        drawSmoothPointAt(&mid, width);
    }
    else
    {
        int r = getNextRandom(&randSeed);
        mid.x += (((r % 101)/100.0)-.5)*displace;
        r = getNextRandom(&randSeed);
        mid.y += (((r % 101)/100.0)-.5)*displace;

        drawLightning(pt1,mid,displace/2,minDisplace,randSeed,width);
        drawLightning(pt2,mid,displace/2,minDisplace,randSeed,width);
    }

    return mid;
} 

void drawSmoothLine(CGPoint *pos1, CGPoint *pos2, float width)
{
    GLfloat lineVertices[12], currentColor[4]; 
    GLint   red, green, blue, alpha;
    CGPoint dir, tan;

    dir.x = pos2->x - pos1->x;
    dir.y = pos2->y - pos1->y;
    float len = sqrtf(dir.x * dir.x + dir.y * dir.y);
    if(len < 0.00001)
        return;
    dir.x = dir.x / len;
    dir.y = dir.y / len;
    tan.x = -width * dir.y;
    tan.y = width * dir.x;

    lineVertices[0] = pos1->x + tan.x;
    lineVertices[1] = pos1->y + tan.y;
    lineVertices[2] = pos2->x + tan.x;
    lineVertices[3] = pos2->y + tan.y;
    lineVertices[4] = pos1->x;
    lineVertices[5] = pos1->y;
    lineVertices[6] = pos2->x;
    lineVertices[7] = pos2->y;
    lineVertices[8] = pos1->x - tan.x;
    lineVertices[9] = pos1->y - tan.y;
    lineVertices[10] = pos2->x - tan.x;
    lineVertices[11] = pos2->y - tan.y;

    glGetFloatv(GL_CURRENT_COLOR, currentColor);
    red = 255.0 * currentColor[0];
    green = 255.0 * currentColor[1];
    blue = 255.0 * currentColor[2];
    alpha = 255.0 * currentColor[3];

    const GLubyte lineColors[] = {
        red, green, blue, 0,
        red, green, blue, 0,
        red, green, blue, alpha,
        red, green, blue, alpha,
        red, green, blue, 0,
        red, green, blue, 0,
    };

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, lineVertices);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, lineColors);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 6);

    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

void drawSmoothPointAt(CGPoint *position, float width)
{
    GLfloat pntVertices[2*6], currentColor[4]; 
    GLint   red, green, blue, alpha;

    pntVertices[0] = position->x;
    pntVertices[1] = position->y;
    pntVertices[2] = position->x - width;
    pntVertices[3] = position->y - width;
    pntVertices[4] = position->x - width;
    pntVertices[5] = position->y + width;
    pntVertices[6] = position->x + width;
    pntVertices[7] = position->y + width;
    pntVertices[8] = position->x + width;
    pntVertices[9] = position->y - width;
    pntVertices[10] = position->x - width;
    pntVertices[11] = position->y - width;

    glGetFloatv(GL_CURRENT_COLOR, currentColor);
    red = 255.0 * currentColor[0];
    green = 255.0 * currentColor[1];
    blue = 255.0 * currentColor[2];
    alpha = 255.0 * currentColor[3];

    const GLubyte pntColors[] = {
        red, green, blue, alpha,
        red, green, blue, 0,
        red, green, blue, 0,
        red, green, blue, 0,
        red, green, blue, 0,
        red, green, blue, 0,
    };

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, pntVertices);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, pntColors);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 6);

    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing WAY too many calculations to get the effect you want

i dont want to make you rewrite your code..but look into bezier curve through point

[here](http://jsdraw2d.jsfiction.com/demo/curvesbezier.htm) is what i mean (set the tension to 0.5 or smth..to get lightning-like effect)

do that..or just make a bunch or random generated images (lightning) and just put them on top of the image to get the lightning effect..what you're doing is too expensive for a small device

Comment: I was thinking that instead of using drawSmoothLine and drawSmoothPointAt, I could texture map the line. But, so far I can't find get it to work.

Comment: well..let me just give you an idea: so..you need to "strike" something with lightning. What you're doing there is drawing the lightning in code ( which is very expensive). What i would do is this: make like..100(or more) images with lightning(random images)with the strike point exactly in the middle of width. So the only thing you'll have to do in code is to get a random number from 1 to 100..and place that image at some distance right above the thing you want to hit. After that..just blink and fade it out.Each image it'll be like 20 kb large..but it worth it. And you wont need all that code

Comment: Or..do what i did: generate a set of random images in a separate thread in the first run of the app (if you're worried about app size) and then do what i said above. The advantage of this is that you wont be constrained by space..so you could generate thousands (but for a lightning effect..100 is more than enough..after all..when you see 50 lightnings ...they start to look the same)

Answer (score 1):

Your FPS will dramatically improve if you import your lightning as PNG images in a batch node texture. Assuming you have multiple lightning images firing from different directions simultaneously, this will only result in one total call to OpenGL, and that call will not have drawing logic since the images will have already been created outside the app.